# Memory usage of a PBS job over time

Tags: pbs

I want to measure the memory usage of a job over time. I understand that I can use `qstat -f <job id>` to obtain the current memory usage. However, is there a way to track the memory usage over time? Perhaps I could write a bash script that would keep polling `qstat` and record the measurements over time.

Comment: Perhaps I could use valgrind with massif. See: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that TORQUE reports is the virtual memory usage found in /proc/pid/stat. TORQUE does not offer a utility for saving this over time and profiling a job, but you could create one by regularly polling qstat (or writing an application that calls the API) and storing the results as you have suggested.